# Merge Sort algorithm

Tags: c++, mergesort

What could be the best algorithm for "Merge Sort" in C++ where the memory must be used "most effectively"? I just know the standard way to do this, but that's not the most effective way how to use the memory.
This is the only variant which I know:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int arr1[20]= {0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
int arr2[14]= {0,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,40,41,42,43};
int arr3[34];
int indexA=0, indexB=0, indexC=0;

while((indexA<20) && (indexB<14)) {
    if(arr1[indexA] < arr2[indexB]) {
        arr3[indexC] = arr1[indexA];
        indexA++;
    }
    else {
        arr3[indexC] = arr2[indexB];
        indexB++;
    }
    indexC++;
}

while(indexA<20) {
    arr3[indexC] = arr1[indexA];
    indexA++;
    indexC++;
}

while(indexB<14) {
    arr3[indexC] = arr2[indexB];
    indexB++;
    indexC++;
}

for (int i=0; i<34; i++)
    cout << arr3[i] << " ";
return 0;
}
```

**Can anyone please advise me a better algorithm for "Merge Sort" which uses the memory in "more effective" way? It can also not be with arrays.**

Thank You very much!

Comment: What you have is only the merge, not the sort.

Comment: This outline was put together by the CPSC faculty where I study. It is in Java, not C++, but the overall idea is what is significant here. http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~harrison/Java/sorting-demo.html

Comment: Oh, yeah, he does... by the way, the standard "compare the first element against the first element of the other list" is an optimal method.  Don't worry about the merge part; you can't get it to be faster.

Answer (score 2):

The usual problem with merge sort is that for every recursion, you end up using a whole new piece of memory.  This turns out to need O(N*log(n)) memory.  It turns out that if you're a bit more clever, you can do this with linear O(N) memory.  Just don't make new arrays, and swap the elements as needed around within the original one.

Comment: Note, that as stated in Matt Helm's link, that this would make your running time slow down to O(N^2).

Comment: I am familiar with a linked list too. 
First, I need 2 linked lists and then combine them into the third linked list? 
Because, how much I know, "merge sort" just stick together 2 already sorted data structures into the 3rd one and then sort that 3rd data structure. Or am I wrong?

How do you think - how could I use linked lists here?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont see how you end up using O(N*lg(n)). Each stack frame is constant and not a function of "n". So, it should be c*lg(n) and hence lg(n).

Answer (score 0):

By the Algorithm nature - Merge Sort need an additional space of the Same Size of the Array you are trying to Sort.

A kind of answer to your question. The book "Data Structures & Algorithms in Java - Second Edition by Robert Lafore" has an example that used only an duplicate array of the same size instead of creating multiple sub array. You can find the program @

http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~sriram/21/fall07/code/mergeSort.java

The following example is just to explain the mergesort in simple way.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class SimpleMergeSort {

void mergeSort(int [] arr)
{
    if( arr.length <= 1)
        return;

    int mid = arr.length / 2;
    int [] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, mid);
    int [] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, mid, arr.length);
    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);
    merge(left,right,arr);
}

void merge(int [] left, int [] right, int[] arr)
{
    int arrIndex = 0;
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;

    //both left and right are not empty
    while( leftIndex < left.length && rightIndex < right.length)
    {
        if( left[leftIndex] < right[rightIndex])
        {
            arr[arrIndex++] = left[leftIndex++];
        }
        else
        {
            arr[arrIndex++] = right[rightIndex++];
        }
    }

    //if left still has some content
    while(leftIndex < left.length)
    {
        arr[arrIndex++] = left[leftIndex++];
    }

    //if right still has some content
    while(rightIndex < right.length)
    {
        arr[arrIndex++] = right[rightIndex++];
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] array = new int[10];

    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = random.nextInt(1000);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    SimpleMergeSort sort = new SimpleMergeSort();
    sort.mergeSort(array);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

instead of using merge and sorting in the main u could have used recursion which would have decreased your load in manually computing and dividing the array into two parts `enter code here`mid =beg+end/2;a[beg,.....,end] //so 
a1[beg,...mid] //and 
a2[]mid+1,....end]`then call the recursion functions check the base case carefully`if(big